# Discord.js async not recording answers

Tags: javascript, discord.js, async.js

I had the following code

```
const schduele3 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('What time will should people start joining?')
        .setColor('BLUE')
        .setDescription('Send your message within 15 seconds! Make sure to include a time zone!')
message.channel.send(schduele3)
const msgs3 = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, {max:1, time:15000})
const time = msgs3.content
```

and it is saying stuff I entered is undefined, any tips?

Answer (score 0):

`Channel#awaitMessages` returns a collection of all of the collected messages after the condition was met (AKA the max amount of messages that need to be collected in the options - In your case, one). From this logic, this collection does not have a `content` property, only do the message objects inside of it do. If you want the first collected message, you should use `.first()` .

#### Final Code

```
const schduele3 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('What time will should people start joining?')
        .setColor('BLUE')
        .setDescription('Send your message within 15 seconds! Make sure to include a time zone!')
message.channel.send(schduele3)
const msgs3 = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, {
  max: 1, 
  time: 15000
})
const time = msgs3.first().content
```